# Beautiful Soup taking long time for specific sites

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi

I'm using Beautiful Soup in a script to scrape a couple of sites. Most of them work very well; I'm used to seeing anywhere between 0.01 to 0.02 seconds for those parses on my main computer. However, when I try to scrape links from certain sites, for example slickdeals.net, I'm seeing anywhere between 0.9 to 2 seconds; almost 100 times slower. It's not too bad on my main computer, but this is a script I plan to run on my Raspberry Pi 3 model B and on that, it takes on average anywhere between 30 to 40 seconds for links on this site (with a rare 60+ seconds occasionally).

Since my main computer is much more powerful than my Pi, concurrently scraping 20+ of links from this site takes about 6 - 10 seconds altogether (with the combined total of every other site being negligible in comparison). However on my Pi, it can take upwards of 240+ seconds (every other site finishes within a few seconds). I'm aiming to run the script every minute, so that takes way too long. Is this just an issue with this specific site? Or is there something I can do to reduce the time? Here is the relevant code that I use:

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(parseStuff, urls)
def parseStuff(url):
    ... ## doing some stuff before scraping
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
    try:
        pageContents = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        openurlArray.append((url, pageContents)) ## using this for other stuff later
        start2 = time.time()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pageContents, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(['span','div'], attrs={'class': possibleClasses[urlName]})) ## looking for a different value for class depending on the site, will either be in div or span tag
        end2 = time.time()
        time_taken2 = end2 - start2
        print("soup stuff for " + url + " took " + str(time_taken2) + " seconds")
```

Comment: you need to use `concurrent.futures` or `threading` in general.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't manage to cut down the time beautiful soup takes, but I managed to work around the issue. I switched to using regex instead and that lowered the time to less than 0.1 seconds on my Pi. It's messier because of the many cases of regex, but it works better in my use case.